# CollectionView header

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Forms version 4.2.0.848062
  - iOS:  iPhone 8 iOS 13.1
  - Android: 9.0

In iOS => CollectionView.Header doesnt work. image => https://ibb.co/30yw2ZY

In Android works fine. image => https://ibb.co/DLQxr74

Example>>

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding AllNotes}" >
    <CollectionView.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Frame OutlineColor="Black"
                        HasShadow="True"
                        CornerRadius="20" 
                        Margin="20,40"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Ahorrado* este mes"/>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </CollectionView.Header>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView>
                <Frame Margin="10,6" BackgroundColor="Gray" CornerRadius="20">
                    <Label Text="test" FontSize="Title"/>
                </Frame>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: You can mark my post as answer ,which will help more people.

Answer (score 6):

It seems a design issue in Xamarin.Forms for iOS . You should set the **CollectionView.Footer** at same time . You can set the content as empty if you don't want it to show anything.

```
<CollectionView.Footer>
 <Grid>

 </Grid>
</CollectionView.Footer>
```

Comment: Hello @Lucas, I've got a similar problem explained in this [repo](https://github.com/Daniele-Tentoni/xamarin-collection-view-example): I have the Header and the Footer, but Header component is not visible by default, I've to scroll down to make it visible. You have any advice?