# Xamarin.Forms CollectionView unexpected header hiding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms.shell

I've created a sample app at this [repo](https://github.com/Daniele-Tentoni/xamarin-collection-view-example) to show you that my collection view with an header hide it at loading, showing it instead when I rotate the emulator. Anyone have any advice?

I'm opened to all solutions, even picking a plugin to solve this.

Edit: thanks to [Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58411585/10220116), the situation it's better, but not resolved by 100%. Adding an empty footer, doesn't let Header to be visible at first loading, but scrolling down the collection view make it visible. Any other advice?

Comment: So anyone else reading this doesn’t have to hunt through the source: The class is HeadedCollection/Views/ItemPage.xaml. Its a CollectionView inside a RefreshView.

Comment: If you add a HeightRequest property on the header (on StackLayout), does that help? I realize it isn’t always desirable to put a fixed height, but maybe it can be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Add Margin="0" to the refresh view should solve the problem.